# Google display network ad for people with the remarketing tag has no impressions

Tags: advertising, google-ads, remarketing

I created a display network ad. 
I set up an automatic bid and on campaigns management it says "eligible".

My display network list has 120 items (people with remarketing tag).

However I don't have any impression.

```
Ad group  Status    Default Max. CPC         Clicks Impr. CTR      Avg. CPC Cost     Avg. Pos.
Total - all but removed ad groups            0      0     0.00%    $0.00    $0.00    0.0
Total - Search                               0      0     0.00%    $0.00    $0.00    0.0
Total - Display Network                      0      0     0.00%    $0.00    $0.00    0.0
Total - all ad groups                        0      0     0.00%    $0.00    $0.00    0.0
```

Comment: Remarketing is people that have already visited your website and are now on other websites where Google can show ads.   How much traffic does your website get?  If it isn't much, then Google may not have enough inventory to show any impressions.